# Spinners in a TableLayout behave werid

Tags: android, xml, textview, spinner

I'm working on an energy calculator. I want the user to use a spinner for selecting if he wants weeks or months calculated. I have the spinner's  width set to "wrap_content" wich should show the first option of the spinner, right? The spinner only shows as a little triangle and a line (So an empty spinner (?)) If I click it it works normally but the aesthetics are horrible. It seems to me, that the center of the 3 elements (a text view) just fills too much space (I tried setting it to "wrap_content" and to a number of pixels)
Thanks for your answers

This is my **activity_main.xml**:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ABE013"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textViewWatt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Watt"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/watt"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewKanton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kanton"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/kantone"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp">
        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/hrsTag"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textViewHrsTag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stunden pro Tag"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/malPro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="20sp">
        </Spinner>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/malProText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Mal pro"
            android:textSize="20sp">
        </TextView>

        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/wm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textSize="20sp">
        </Spinner>


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_span="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Los!"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

This is my **strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>

<string name="app_name">EneratorRechner</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<string-array name="kantone">
    <item>Kanton Auswählen</item>
    <item>Aargau</item>
    <item>Appenzell Ausserrhoden</item>
    <item>Appenzell Innerrhoden</item>
    <item>Basel-Land</item>
    <item>Basel-Stadt</item>
    <item>Bern</item>
    <item>Firbourg</item>
    <item>Genf</item>
    <item>Glarus</item>
    <item>Graubünden</item>
    <item>Jura</item>
    <item>Luzern</item>
    <item>Neuenburg</item>
    <item>Obwalden</item>
    <item>Schaffhausen</item>
    <item>Schwyz</item>
    <item>Solothurn</item>
    <item>St. Gallen</item>
    <item>Tessin</item>
    <item>Thurgau</item>
    <item>Uri</item>
    <item>Waadt</item>
    <item>Wallis</item>¨
    <item>Zug</item>
    <item>Zürich</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="hrsTag">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>13</item>
    <item>14</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>17</item>
    <item>18</item>
    <item>19</item>
    <item>21</item>
    <item>22</item>
    <item>23</item>
    <item>24</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="malPro">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>13</item>
    <item>14</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>17</item>
    <item>18</item>
    <item>19</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>21</item>
    <item>22</item>
    <item>23</item>
    <item>24</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>26</item>
    <item>27</item>
    <item>28</item>
    <item>29</item>
    <item>30</item>
    <item>31</item>

</string-array>
<string-array name="wm">
    <item>Woche</item>
    <item>Monat</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textViewWatt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Watt"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/watt"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_height="55dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewKanton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Kanton"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/kantone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/hrsTag"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textViewHrsTag"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Stunden pro Tag"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/malPro"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:textSize="20sp">
        </Spinner>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/malProText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Mal pro"
            android:textSize="20sp">
        </TextView>

        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/wm"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:textSize="20sp">
        </Spinner>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Los!"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```